Cauchy's integral formula and maximum modulus theorem (?)
Some time ago I came upon the following problem:
Let $D = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \colon |z| < 1 \}$ be the unitary disk and let $f, g \colon \overline{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ (defined on the disk and its boundary) be functions countinuous in $\overline{D}$ and holomorhpic in $D$. Prove that if

$|f(z)| \leqslant 1$, $|g(z)| \leqslant 2$ for $|z|=1$, $\text{im } z \geqslant 0$,
$|f(z)| \leqslant 3$, $|g(z)| \leqslant 1$ for $|z|=1$, $\text{im } z \leqslant 0$,

then $|f(0)| \cdot |g(0)| \leqslant \frac{5}{2}$.
It feels quite obvious to use Cauchy's integral formula and divide the circle into two semicircles and then estimate the two integrals, but I'm having doubts - is it formally OK to use the theorem if the functions are not necessarily analytic on teh boundary? Perhaps one should estimate a smaller circle and use the maximum modulus theorem?
Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Yes, it is OK to consider a smaller disk and then pass to the limit. This is a standard trick for such questions.
